# How to click on the web element with Selenium?

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I want to click on the `Element`. I have following js code that does that trick:

```
$('#targetparam13 dd span.value')[2].click()
```

This is the code I am trying to get the same action using c# webdriver:

```
WDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"targetparam13\"]/dd/ul/li[3]/a/span")).Click();
```

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

python bindings but surely there should be a similar method for C# bindings:

```
driver.execute_script("$('#targetparam13 dd span.value')[2].click()")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use exactly the same CSS selector in `By.CssSelector` locator:

```
WDriver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#targetparam13 dd span.value"))[2].Click();
```

`FindElements` method here would return us a list of "Web Elements", from which we can get the third element and click it.

Comment: Message = "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with"

Comment: @sidux okay, this is a different problem now. There could be multiple reasons you've got the error..I think the best course of action here is to create a new question and add more details about the problem providing the url to the page under test or html of the page including the complete code you are currently executing and the stacktrace..thanks for understanding.